# Is there a drink in Italy similar to kvass?

Tags: non-alcoholic

[Kvass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvass) is a low alcoholic drink made of (usually rye) bread. Is there something similar in Italy (like [malt beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malt_beer) in Germany)? Or maybe is it possible to buy kvass in big supermarkets?

Comment: May be related: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamalz but I'm not sure. This (German) drink is also popular in Alto Adige / Südtirol, German speaking county in Northern Italy.

Comment: @MattAllegro Karamalz is close indeed (it's a sort of malt beer I mentioned in the question) but not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to be a Russian/Eastern European store. There are some in many larger Italian cities, search for "negozio russo" or "alimentari russo" in an area you are interested in. Some possibilities:

**Rome**

- "Kozak" - Via dei Conciatori, 1c
- "Galychnya" - Via Santa Maria delle Fornaci, 6

**Verona**

- "Il Negozio Tipico Russo", Via Vincenzo Cabianca, 10

**Cagliari**

- "Алёнушка" - via Francesco Carrara, 22

**Genoa**

- "Angolo dell'Est" Vicolo Canneto il Curto

**Carpi**

- "Europa-Est" - via Trento Trieste 34/a

It may pay to call ahead to see if they carry Kvass, if you can find a phone number.